# Firebase Integration With SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Firebase error with swiftui when import Firebase in App delegate.

It says

> [NSException raise:kFirebaseCoreErrorDomain
>                   format:@"`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find "
>                          @"a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one "
>                          @"from %@.",
>                          kPlistURL];

Deleting pods file and installing again

> [NSException raise:kFirebaseCoreErrorDomain
>                   format:@"`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find "
>                          @"a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one "
>                          @"from %@.",
>                          kPlistURL];

Answer (score 2):

you will need to go to console.firebase.google.com and login with you google account.

1.Add Project or open you existing created project

2.On dashboard you will see the platforms click on iOS Icon and **fill up the details.**

[image]

3.you will prompt to download a GoogleService-Info.plist download it

4.Drag the downloaded file into you iOS Xcode project in the main Hierarchy of your project

[image]

5.In Appdelegate add this code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
```

Comment: the question is about swiftUI not storyboard